# Makefile always recompiles binaries, because target doesn't exist

Tags: c, windows, makefile, gnu-make

I just started to take a look at Makefiles and already have a problem.
I tried to create a simple makefile, which only compiles one main.c file.

```
# Compiler and flags
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra 

# Source and object files
SRCS = main.c 
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Executable name
TARGET = myprogram

# Targets
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

When calling make for the first time (when the main.o doesn't exist) the makefile works as expected. (the main.o and myprogram.exe is created).
When calling make again, without changing the source code at all, the executable is rebuilt.
Taking a look at the debug results with `make -d` tells me that the .o file is up to date, but the myprogram target doesn't exist.

```
No need to remake target 'main.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'myprogram'.
 Must remake target 'myprogram'.
Makefile:16: update target 'myprogram' due to: target does not exist
gcc -Wall -Wextra  -o myprogram main.o
```

All files are located in one src directory.

I'm afraid that my understanding of makefiles isn't quite there yet, and I made a simple mistake tham I am unable to find myself.

Comment: Is it creating `myprogram` or `myprogram.exe`? The makefile expects it to create `myprogram`. If it actually creates `myprogram.exe`, that should be the target in the makefile.

Comment: The command you're running: `gcc -Wall -Wextra  -o myprogram main.o` should create the file `myprogram`; that's what the `-o myprogram` option does.  After you run make, does the `myprogram` file exist?  If you run `ls *myprogram*` what do you see?  This isn't a make problem, per se, it's something about your compiler or your environment, that we can't see from this question.

Comment: Doesn't the `clean` finally delete the object file, so next time it has to be remade?

Comment: Only if the `clean` target is actually built, @WeatherVane.  Based on the makefile presented, that will happen only if it is explicitly requested on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback and help.
So it turns out, that when i change the target from myprogram to myprogram.exe I get the expected result and no recompilation is happening.
Does this indicate that I use some wired compiler or os settings?
Because most other makefiles I saw online dont need to add the .exe file extension.

Comment: @Carlo Most makefile users are using a Linux/Unix operating system, which doesn't distinguish files by extension. When they run `gcc ... -o myfile ...` it creates a file literally called `myfile`.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for the answer makes a lot of senes.